# segmentation fault in TCL @ Tcl_WriteChars ()

Tags: linux, tcl

We are observing a segmentaiton fault in TCL @ Tcl_WriteChars ().

Looking for a answers on the follwoing:

- Which scenarios lead to Tcl_WriteChars () segmentation fault
- How to fix

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Comment: When I try to run a TCL script, I see it aborts with "Segmentation Fault(core dumpled). On further getting the backtrace of that core file, I could find that it is because of follwoing.,                                                                                                       Reading symbols from /u/testing/st-tcl/auto/lib/Stcommands/stCommands.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /u/testing/st-tcl/auto/lib/Stcommands/stCommands.so
#0  0xf76cd302 in Tcl_WriteChars () from /u/testing/st-tcl/auto/lib/libtcl8.3.so

Comment: One thing you should do is to upgrade to a more current Tcl version. While it's unlikely that `Tcl_WriteChars` itself causes the problem, each of the three arguments to it could potentially lead to a segmentation fault if they are invalid. You need to verify that you understand how the arguments should be constructed and that you are indeed passing valid arguments.

Comment: Tcl 8.3 hasn't been supported in quite a few years. Tcl 8.4 is no longer supported. Tcl 8.5 is drawing to the end of its support period (it's had 8 years of support so far). We recommend 8.6 for all new work.

Comment: You need a symbols build and a _full_ stack trace in order for us to get enough information to be even able to consider starting to help.

Comment: Hi All, We upgraded the TCL version frpm 8.3 to 8.6 and it is resolved.